# Cannot get SQL query to store results into variables

Tags: c#, sql, casting, scalar

Hi I need to put in the result of `I01` into a variable. Same for `I02` and `I03` \
I am using C#.

I can put the result of `FName` and `LName` into a variable fine using a `Data Reader`, but I cannot figure out how to read the queries inside the ( ).

```
//SELECT STATEMENT IN A STRING

SELECT Distinct FName, LName, 
I01 = (SELECT INAME FROM tbl_interests WHERE IID = FK_Interest_01), 
I02 = (SELECT INAME FROM tbl_interests WHERE IID = FK_Interest_02), 
I03 = (SELECT INAME FROM tbl_interests WHERE IID = FK_Interest_03) 
FROM tbl_students

//SQL CONNECTION HERE

while (dr.Read())
{
    int interest 01 = (Int16)dr["I01"];
    int interest 01 = (Int16)dr["I01"];
    int interest 01 = (Int16)dr["I01"];
}
```

The error I get is : **Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.**

However they do return integers

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What is the value of your `dr["I01"]` exactly when you debug?

Comment: it returns a number that relates to another table - so 101, or 102

Comment: **What is this syntax ? `int interest 01 = (Int16)dr["I01"];` ? what is this 01 doing there ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What is this syntax ?

`int interest 01 = (Int16)dr["I01"];` ?

Fix it.

Also

Int16 is not an integer (32)

- int and int32 are one and the same (32-bit integer)
- int16 is short int (2 bytes or 16-bits)

I believe that you return from SQL an INT type.

Therefor you should cast to int ( no need int32)

Comment: what is INAME's type ?

Comment: I am not sure (obviously) but is it because the dr["I01"]; is not reading inside the (select) queries?

Comment: It is in int - and it does return data in sql server

Comment: Waht is the result of `dr["I01"].GetType()` /

Comment: I get this returned : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to 'string'

Comment: **no**! run this :      `while (dr.Read())
    {
        Console.Write(dr["I01"].GetType());
        Console.Write(dr["I02"].GetType());
        Console.Write(dr["I03"].GetType());
    }`

Comment: chk the value for `dr["I01"].GetType().Name` that should tell you the exact type

Comment: @AppDeveloper That's what i'm after

Comment: Sorry took a while, to sort out in my method - I get 3 strings

Comment: dr["I01"].GetType().Name - when I type that in It prints string for each one. The value it returns is the ID of another table

Comment: dr["I01"].GetType().Name  should return the type not a number . you're doing something wrong

Comment: The type is a string - but that is why I am casting it into an int, because it is suppose to be a number. It works if I do a straight select statement, but ever since I put it in the ( & ) it doesn't

Comment: I need to do that, but I need to return 3 columns (not rows) from the same table.

Comment: change each row in the sql `SELECT INAME FROM tbl_interests WHERE...` to `SELECT cast (INAME as int) FROM tbl_interests WHERE ...`

Comment: Cool got it - I see where I went wrong, My FK is relating to an Int, but I am requesting the name of the FK which is a varchar. - so it spat the dummy at me :-) Thanks for helping me through it.